# Joomla links ok on live site but incorrect on local server

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, localhost, joomla1.5, mamp

My Joomla site has been running with no problems live. I wanted to make some changes to it, so I downloaded the entire site and database to my localhost. Everything shows fine when I load the local site, however all the internal links have changed. For example one now shows the link to be:

```
http://localhost:8888/centrevision/http:/localhost/centrevision/dvr-systems/view-all-products.html
```

where it should be:

```
http://localhost:8888/centrevision/dvr-systems/view-all-products.html
```

I'm sure this is just a case of a setting in the config file or the .htaccess, but I can't figure out what specifically to change.

The Joomla version is 1.5.26, and I'm using MAMP as the local server.

Any help appreciated.

...
htaccess

```
##
# @version $Id: htaccess.txt 21064 2011-04-03 22:12:19Z dextercowley $
# @package Joomla
# @copyright Copyright (C) 2005 - 2010 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL
# Joomla! is Free Software
##

#####################################################
#  READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
#
#####################################################

##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks
#
# mod_rewrite in use

RewriteEngine On

########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
## Deny access to extension xml files (uncomment out to activate)
#<Files ~ "\.xml$">
#Order allow,deny
#Deny from all
#Satisfy all
#</Files>
## End of deny access to extension xml files
# Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits

########## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
########## End - Custom redirects

#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

RewriteBase /

########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section
```

Comment: it might be due to url rewrites in .htaccess file

Comment: In htaccess I've tried commenting out 'RewriteEngine On', 'Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch' and uncommenting 'Options +FollowSymLinks', 'mod_rewrite in use' and 'RewriteBase /' one at a time, but I'm still getting the same result on the links

Comment: try to turn off sef from joomla admin.

Comment: I've tried SEF both on and off, and still getting same issue.

Comment: it might be due to "mamp". Try using "wamp" indead. http://wampserver.com/

Comment: I'm working off a Mac and have no access to Windows.

Comment: I'd put money on the htaccess. When you changed the htaccess did you reboot the server before checking the url? It's probably a good idea to try that after making changes with Joomla too. If possible, could you post the content of your htaccess file? On a slightly different track what type of server are you using for your live site?

Comment: I thought that may be it, however, I've now tried changing settings and resetting the server each time, but it's still not working. I don't have access to the live servers details, I've only got ftp access to it.

Comment: Wow I spent forever on this. Fixed by prefixing live_site with  `http://`

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem on a live server. What helped was adding the live site in the configuration.php file:

```
    var $live_site = 'http://localhost:8888/centrevision';
```

Hope this works for you too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately adding that didn't seem to make any difference.